# How to do tracing of caliper benchmarks execution ?

Tags: caliper

How can I see console output in "running" mode (in --debug I can see it). Does caliper creates execution log? How to access it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, Caliper 0.5 doesn't have very good support for this.  The reason is that if you're really performing a benchmark, extra I/O may degrade performance.

Caliper 1.0 gives you a few more options.  By default, console output is still hidden, but adding `--verbose` will display any console output from the worker.  It will also send logging to `~/.caliper/log/`.  Logging configuration can be overridden in `~/.caliper/logging.properties`.  If you need more control over output and logging, I recommend checking out Caliper 1.0 from HEAD and giving it a try.  We hope to have a pre-built beta release soon.